# Unwanted gap between elements with position:absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have an issue that looks like a detail, but I want to understand why that happens.
It's about positioning. 
I have absolute position to the child element with top:0 left:0 .

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:0;
```

1. Why the child element extends x axis and ?
2. Why the child element has the small gap between the edge of the top body and the element itself(y-axis)?
   ...since the top and left attributes are set to zero.
   [here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bill123/an2j6qq3/10/)

Comment: What does "Why the child element extends x axis and ?" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because `position:absolute` will try to find an ancestor whose `position` is not default value (static). In you demo there isn't such ancestor, so `#rel` is positioned relate to the document root (body element).
2. `#rel` has a defualt margin value. try `margin:0` on `#rel` and see the result

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/myst/an2j6qq3/11/)

Comment: Clear answer! Thanks a lot

Comment: @BillysGtr that's it? no up vote or accepted answer? :)

Comment: Unfortunately my reputation is to low to vote. require 15 to vote up!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give margin:0 to the paragraph i.e #rel, so there will be no white-space at the top.